# Is my 600mA, 9V adapter suitable for a MB102 breadboard power supply?

Tags: breadboard, adapter

I've recently bought a 600mA, 9V adapter thinking that it would be suitable for a MB102 breadboard power supply but have now read that the maximum output of the MB102 breadboard power supply is 700mA and people in the community are recommending 1A, 9V adapters. Would my 600mA one still work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will still work fine, you just can't draw quite as much peak current.

Those numbers are pretty "optimistic".. if you draw 0.7A from the 5V supply the SOT223 AMS1117  alone would be attempting to dissipate almost 2.5W and if you drew it from the 3.3V output, the total dissipation on the little PCB would be about 4W. Typical schematic from [here](https://protosupplies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/YwRobot-Power-Module-Schematic.jpg):

[image]

2.5W probably represents 300°C+ junction temperature rise from ambient (120°C-160°C/W) so the regulator will certainly shut down and it's unhealthy for it to do that.

Linear regulators are generally limited by thermal considerations, in terms of continuous current capability. Unless you anticipate working with a circuit that draws brief high current pulses from the power supply you won't notice any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you expect. 9V input is higher than what is required and will just make regulators heat up more than with lower voltage.

The lower the input voltage is, the less it heats up with the same current. It should not require more than 7V.

With recommended output current less than 700mA anyway, you are not missing much from the maximum if your supply only gives out 600mA max.

If people suggest 1A 9V adapters, it's likely because people statistically just have 1A adapters and they appear to work fine, and they don't have adapters that have less current output.

Comment: Thank you as well. The adapter is actually one where you can select the voltage i.e. 3, 4.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 9 &12V. Should I go for 5V or 6V then? Sorry if this appears a stupid question but I'm still pretty new to electronics.

Comment: @JR Impossible to say what kind of adapter you have and what voltage you should use on it. Is it regulated or unregulated? Linear or switch mode? If you set it to 9V or 7.5V, do you measure the set voltage or something else?

Comment: It says that it's switch mode if that helps. And a max. of 600mA on all output voltages. Is it still suitable? If not, which power supply should I get?

Comment: Oh, and also what jack size please? Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: If you don't need more then that is enough. I can't know if it is suitable for your use or not. If you need more than 600mA then it isn't. We cannot suggest you what to buy as it is against the rules of this site for very good reasons. Basically, your question is about using a product, not design, which is also off-topic. I don't know what jack you need, you likely know it better or can read it from the product manual.